Trying to change a range variable to an array in mathcad prime v10
Attached is a screenshot of the mathcad sheet. I've used this method before to turn a range variable to an array and it worked in mathcad prime v2. My company upgraded to mathcad prime v10.this is what I had in v2 and then tried to do the same in v10
All I want to do is stack these two range variables on top of each other, and then I'll eventually augment them with some other range variables. However, I cannot figure out how to get the range variables to turn into arrays in this new version.
I was expecting V10 to work the same as V2. Everything I can find online gives this as a "way" to turn range variables into arrays. And all the tutorials i can find on youtube do this.
mathcad ptc resource for this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyNi2YYHlPE - however this was not in V10. But i wouldnt expect this method to be invalid with the new version
Does anyone know what Im doing wrong, or what I can do to do this? I need the range variable to be turned into an array.

This was a change introduced in Mathcad Prime 10.   The solution is to create a function to iterate over the range and return the corresponding vector. (this has always technically been the preferred method; the method you've been using is an unintended side-effect that has proved useful, but combining a definition and evaluation can itself lead to erroneous assignments).
The following thread contains a Mathcad Prime 10 worksheet that evaluates several range->vector functions, including variants that flatten nested arrays.   The simpler forms should suffice for your needs.
https://community.ptc.com/t5/Mathcad/Vectorization-Function-Performance-Comparison/m-p/980707/highlight/true#M214664
